# JavaFX TableView bold whole row iff `message.isUnread()==true`

Tags: uitableview, javafx

I am trying to replicate Gmail behavior in Javafx TableView. Row of new Unread message should be shown in bold. Here is what I was able to do so far:

[image]

I can change background of the whole row, and bold a cell, but can't bold the whole row.
How to explain Javafx to do this?

```
for each Cell cell in tableview: 
    get Message m corresponding to row.
    String style = m.isUnread() ? "
    cell.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: 800" : "-fx-font-weight: 100")




import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Message {
    final static public ObservableList<Message> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new Message("Bob", "Where are you?", true, true),
            new Message("Elise", "Payment", false, false),
            new Message("Charlie", "Read this book: 'Clean code'", true, true),
            new Message("Oscar", "Golf class tonight", true, false),
            new Message("Sam", "How is your TableView progress?", false, true),
            new Message("Alice", "Latte", true, true)
    );

    final private String  name;
    final private String  title;
    private boolean isUnread;
    private boolean isArchived;

    public Message(String name, String title, boolean isUnread, boolean isArchived) {
        this.name = name; this.title = title; this.isUnread = isUnread;this.isArchived = isArchived;
    }
    public String  getName()    { return name;    }
    public String  getTitle()  { return title;  }
    public boolean getIsUnread() { return isUnread; }
    public boolean getisArchived() { return isArchived; }


    public void setIsUnread(boolean isUnread) { this.isUnread = isUnread;     }
 }
```

MyTable.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;


public class MyTable extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { launch(args); }
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Inbox");

        // create a table.
        TableView<Message> table = new TableView(Message.data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(makeStringColumn("Name", "name", 150), makeStringColumn("Title", "title", 300), makeBooleanColumn("New", "isUnread", 150));
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        table.setPrefHeight(250);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
        stage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("message.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.show();

        // highlight the table rows depending upon whether we expect to get paid.
        int i = 0;
        for (Node n: table.lookupAll("TableRow")) {
            if (n instanceof TableRow) {
                TableRow row = (TableRow) n;
                if (table.getItems().get(i).getIsUnread()) {
                    row.getStyleClass().add("isReadRow");
                } else {
                    row.getStyleClass().add("isUnreadRow");
                }
                i++;
                if (i == table.getItems().size())
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private TableColumn<Message, String> makeStringColumn(String columnName, String propertyName, int prefWidth) {
        TableColumn<Message, String> column = new TableColumn<>(columnName);
        column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Message, String>(propertyName));
        column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Message, String>, TableCell<Message, String>>() {
            @Override public TableCell<Message, String> call(TableColumn<Message, String> soCalledFriendStringTableColumn) {
                return new TableCell<Message, String>() {
                    @Override public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            setText(item);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        column.setPrefWidth(prefWidth);
        column.setSortable(false);
        return column;
    }

    private TableColumn<Message, Boolean> makeBooleanColumn(String columnName, String propertyName, int prefWidth) {
        TableColumn<Message, Boolean> column = new TableColumn<>(columnName);
        column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Message, Boolean>(propertyName));
        column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Message, Boolean>, TableCell<Message, Boolean>>() {
            @Override public TableCell<Message, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Message, Boolean> soCalledFriendBooleanTableColumn) {
                return new TableCell<Message, Boolean>() {
                    @Override public void updateItem(final Boolean item, final boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            setText(item.toString());
                            this.getStyleClass().add(item ? "isUnreadCell" : "isReadCell");
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
        column.setPrefWidth(prefWidth);
        column.setSortable(false);
        return column;
    }
}
```

(Message.css)

```
   .column-header-background         { -fx-background-color: azure;       }
   .isReadRow                       { -fx-background-color: palegreen;   }
   .isUnreadRow                       { -fx-background-color: yellow;       }
   .isReadCell                      { -fx-font-weight: 100 ; -fx-text-fill: darkgreen;}
   .isUnreadCell                     { -fx-font-weight: 800 ; -fx-text-fill: red;}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the `-fx-font-weight` on the `isReadRow` style class? As the styles _cascade_ it should apply to any cell that doesn't explicitly change it.

Answer (score 3):

To bold a row associate a RowFactory as shown below.

```
table.setPrefHeight(250);
        table.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<Message>, TableRow<Message>>() {
            @Override
            public TableRow<Message> call(TableView<Message> param) {
                final TableRow<Message> row = new TableRow<Message>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Message row, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(row, empty);
                        if (!empty)
                            styleProperty().bind(Bindings.when(row.selectedProperty())
                                    .then("-fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-font-size: 16;")
                                    .otherwise(""));
                    }
                };
                return row;
            }
        });

        stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
```

In the above sample, selectedProperty() function has been called by the Message row. The selectedProperty() function returns the value of boolean variable isUnread. If the isUnread value is true then the whole row will be bolded else it won't be.

```
 final private String  title;
    private boolean isUnread;
    private boolean isArchived;
    private BooleanProperty selected;

    public boolean getSelected() {return selected.get();}
    public BooleanProperty selectedProperty(){return selected;}


    public Message(String name, String title, boolean isUnread, boolean isArchived) {
        this.name = name; this.title = title; this.isUnread = isUnread;this.isArchived = isArchived;
        this.selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty(isUnread);
    }
```

Setting the font style as bold and size to 16 gives following output:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: My answer does work for your question. You are now starting to add features. When you add features or update your program things might break.  Please search or make a question here in SO and don't just disapprove my approved answer.

Comment: I don't want to mislead other devs with the same problem. A partial solution that doesn't quite work if you try to add standard features (sort/filter) is not very useful in a long run. As for points - you got my upvotes elsewhere on your good answers to other questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `PseudoClass`es to denote read/unread rows. Use a `rowFactory` to set the `PseudoClass`es. Also using a property for the read/unread state would be preferable, since this allows you to update the rows without refreshing the whole table:

```
private final BooleanProperty unread;

public void setUnread(boolean value) {
    this.unread.set(value);
}

public boolean isUnread() {
    return this.unread.get();
}

public BooleanProperty unreadProperty() {
    return unread;
}

public Message(String name, String title, boolean isUnread, boolean isArchived) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
    this.unread = new SimpleBooleanProperty(isUnread);
    this.isArchived = isArchived;
}
```

```
final PseudoClass read = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("read");
final PseudoClass unread = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("unread");
table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<Message>() {

    private void setState(boolean readState, boolean unreadState) {
        pseudoClassStateChanged(unread, unreadState);
        pseudoClassStateChanged(read, readState);
    }

    private void setUnreadState(boolean unreadState) {
        setState(!unreadState, unreadState);
    }

    private final ChangeListener<Boolean> unreadListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> setUnreadState(newValue);

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Message item, boolean empty) {
        // remove listener from old item
        Message oldItem = getItem();
        if (oldItem != null) {
            oldItem.unreadProperty().removeListener(unreadListener);
        }

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setState(false, false);
        } else {
            // set appropriate state & add listener
            setUnreadState(item.isUnread());
            item.unreadProperty().addListener(unreadListener);
        }
    }

});

stage.setScene(new Scene(table));
```

```css
.table-row-cell:read {
    -fx-background-color: palegreen;
}

.table-row-cell:unread {
    -fx-background-color: yellow;
}

.table-row-cell:read>.table-cell {
    -fx-font-weight: 100;
    -fx-text-fill: darkgreen;
}

.table-row-cell:unread>.table-cell {
    -fx-font-weight: 800;
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Also make sure to set the `text` of `TableCell`s even if they become empty. Otherwise you could see "ghost content":

```
@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item != null) {
        setText(item);
    } else {
        setText("");
    }
}
```

```
@Override
public void updateItem(final Boolean item, final boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item != null) {
        setText(item.toString());
    } else {
        setText("");
    }
}
```